# Cannot get into a container namespace with bin/bash

Tags: bash, docker, nsenter

In one terminal I have a running container

```
docker container run --rm -it bash
```

In another terminal I want to run bin/bash in the same namespace as the running container above. For that to happen I followed these steps:

Grab the PID of the running container

```
docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} 32d7a757bc05
```

Let say the PID is 3386. When I run

```
sudo nsenter --target 3386 --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid bash
```

I get this error

```
nsenter: failed to execute bash: No such file or directory
```

But if I change `bash` to `sh` as below it works

```
sudo nsenter --target 3386 --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid sh
```

I'm on Centos 7, docker version 20.10.6 and as you have noticed I'm running my container from [bash image](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash). I cannot understand why bash is not working. Can someone please explain this?

**Update**

Just giving a little bit more background. I'm running my Centos as a Vagrant VM. I used `vagrant ssh` to connect to both terminals.

**Vagrantfile**

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "centos/7"
config.vm.provider "hyperv"
end
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but could it be `/bin/bash`?

Comment: Do you mean `sudo nsenter --target 3386 --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid /bin/bash`? If yes, this still does not work

Comment: @KamilCuk As far as I know `docker run , runs a command in a container`. How does it relate to my issue. Could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

What you described actually worked for me:

```
sudo docker container run --rm -it bash
```

In a second terminal:

```
sudo nsenter --target 604861 --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid bash
bash-5.1# which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

where I found the PID the way you described, using `docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} CONTAINERID`.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I added an `update` section to my question above. This is to highlight possible differences between yours and mine and to clarify more how I've set up my env.

Comment: When I ran `sudo nsenter -t 3386 -m /usr/local/bin/bash` it worked. I still cannot explain why it is not working with just `bash` at the end. As I mentioned before `sh` works I don't have to change it to `/bin/sh`.